# swapping variables

Tags: swift, variables

I have this coding question writing in swift:

```
var a = 5
var b = 8

//Without touching any of the exisiting code, can you write 3 lines of 
//code to switch around the values held inside the two variables 
//a and b? And you cannot use any numbers in your code, 
//e.g. you can't just write: 

a = 8; b = 5

//write your answers here 

print("a: \(a)")
print("b: \(b)")
```

The model answer is

```
var c = a
a = b
b = c
```

Question: am I thinking in a wrong direction if my answer to this is:

```
a = \(a+b-a)
b = \(b+a-b)
```

I didn't think about creating a new variable at all..

Comment: The last entry in your model answer should be `b = c` and not `b = a` and that would make it correct.

Comment: Your suggestion can be simplified to `a = b` and `b = a` , which will mean both `a` and `b` will be equal to 8.

Comment: Do you understand why use a third var to do so? If you get your first `a = (a+b-a)`, then `a` is now equals to `8`. So next line you do `b = (b+a-b)`, which is `b = 8 + 8 - 8`. It's exactly the same reason on why use a third var to swap.

Comment: Thanks, @Larme. You really cleared out my confusion!

Answer (score 4):

Duncan C has already pointed out the error in the “model answer”, and Larme has pointed out the flaw in your suggested answer, so I won't address those.

Ignoring the “3 lines” requirement, here's the shortest, and perhaps the clearest, answer:

```
swap(&a, &b)
```

This uses the standard library's `swap` function. Swift requires the `&` sigils to alert you (and anyone else reading the code) that the variables may be modified by the `swap` function.

Here is another correct one-line Swift solution that is more easily extended to rearrange more than just two variables:

```
(a, b) = (b, a)
```

This works because the right side is fully evaluated before any assignments are performed.

Your attempt at a ‘clever’ solution can be fixed by using three computations:

```
a = b - a
b = b - a        // = b0 - (b0 - a0) = b0 - b0 + a0 = a0
a = a + b        // = b0 - a0 + a0 = b0
```

You can find some discussion of this trick in [Hacker's Delight 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321842685) section 2-20 “Exchanging Registers”.

Comment: I'd like to mention that `swap` doesn't perform magic. It uses the 3-lines requirement under the hood.

Comment: It may not be magic, but I wouldn't say it's [mundane](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b5d59edeef390912fd1d7ecdc38c623deb7c9607/stdlib/public/core/MutableCollection.swift#L391).

Comment: Indeed it's not, but eventually there is just `p1→tmp`, `p2→p1`, `tmp→p2`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are thinking about it wrong. The answer is to create a 3rd variable.

Your "model answer" isn't quite right. It should be

```
let c = a  //Save the current value of a - use a let constant since it doesn't change
a = b
b = c      //Put the old value of a into b
```

Your solution would not work as others have pointed out in their comments.

Note that Rob's solution using tuples allows you do make the swap without explicitly creating a temporary variable, but under the covers, it maps both variables into a tuple, which is a value type that holds the current value of your two variables. Thus the effect is the same (a temporary place to hold the values while swapping them.)

Comment: The model answer should be using `let` instead of `var` because `c` is not mutated.

Comment: @vacawama good point. I should have caught that. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple:

```swift
(a, b) = (b, a)
```